# Why PHP include Not Hidden inside the div with bootstrap 4

Tags: php, ajax, html, bootstrap-4

I Used Php include to include the info inside of the modals for the albums and for some reason its including the correct file but its not hidden as i specified in the div class where I have included it. you can visit the music page on https://www.trillumonopoly.com  but here is the code for the music page where i included the musicmodals.php info page. Funny thing is it doesnt display all of the content. just the very last div. why is this even visible? How can I fix? I cant include the code of the music modal page ... too much for the text area... but

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.general {
    background : url("img/parallaxmain1.jpg") repeat fixed 100% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}

.album {
    width: 90%;
    height: 650px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background : url("img/featured.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;
}

.songlist {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 90% !important; 

    height: 200px:
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.albumback {

    background : url("img/featured.jpg") repeat fixed 80% !Important;
     background-size: cover;

}


</style>

</head>
<body><center><font size="2em">

<div class="general">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="col-6 ">
                <img src="img/mediahead.png" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 ">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="discography row container">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#BlueLines" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/011BlueLines/bluelines.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: BLUE LINES & BIG FACES<br>
                Release: 2015<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#YungNGettinIt" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/010YungNGettinIt/yung.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: Yung N Gettin It<br>
                Release: 2014<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#RNL" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/009RNL/rnl.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: RNL<br>
                Release: 2014<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#GodsHand" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/008GodsHand/godshand.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: GodsHand<br>
                Release: 2013<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#AG" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/007IAmAG/IamAGFront.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: ZAREYAH <br>
                Title: I AM A G<br>
                Release: 2011<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#KeepItG" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/006KeepItG/keepItGFront.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: Keep It G<br>
                Release: 2012<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#Gunsmoke" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/005GunsmokeNResin/gunsmoke.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: GunsSMoke & Resin<br>
                Release: 2011<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#Divine1" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/004DGvol1/DGvol1front.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: Divine Grind <br>
                Title: Vol. 1<br>
                Release: 2010<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#PotentAlbum" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/003PotentAlbum/potentalbumfront.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: The Potent Album<br>
                Release: 2006<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#2Potent" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/002The2PotentAlbum/toopotentalbumfront.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: 2 Potent Album<br>
                Release: 2005<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box2"><br>
                <a href="#DoinNumbers" data-lity>
                    <img src="music/001DoinNumbers/DoinNumbersFront.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
                <hr style="background-color:#ffffff"><br>
                <div class="video description">
                Artist: T. Cartel <br>
                Title: Doin Numbers<br>
                Release: 2005<br>
                </div><br>
            </div>




        </div>

</div>
<center>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7512006871298343"
     data-ad-slot="7265345115"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
<!--footer-->
&copy; ILLUMONOPOLY LLC. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. </center>

<div class="d-none invisible">
<?php include("/customers/b/b/3/trillumonopoly.com/httpd.www/pages/musicmodals.php");?>
</div>      

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where are the classes: `d-none` and `invisible` defined?

Comment: they are inside the bootstrap 4 css I believe @Kchason

Comment: Where are the jquery and bootstrap includes?

Comment: the jquery and bootstrap includes are included in my index page. on my website. it loads this page via ajax....

Answer (score 0):

An extra closing  was before the last modal allowing it to close the last div that contained all the modals. Simply removed the closing  and all the content became hidden.